# Python nested list userinput

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have nested list like:

```
users = [['abc', 55.2],['pqr', 23.2],['adsf', 232.12]]
```

how can i take this as input from user in python.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. If you have the list already, why would you need to get it as user input?

Comment: You need ast.literal_eval maybe.

Comment: @AdamSmith. Bro, I want to take the above list as input. It's just example

Comment: I guess the better question is how do you WANT to get it as input? You can present the user with input prompts in all sorts of ways. What do the inner lists (which look like they should be tuples instead, but I digress...) represent? Are you hoping to get all this info from the same user? In one single prompt, or in several? How many elements will be a part of the outer list? Does `inner_element[1]` have to be a `float`?

Comment: Thanks, bro. I got it. looped twice through the list.

Comment: You want input added to a list?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need `ast.literal_eval`. Demo:

```
import ast

user_input = "[['abc', 55.2],['pqr', 23.2],['adsf', 232.12]]"  # as a string

print(ast.literal_eval(user_input))
```

result: `[['abc', 55.2], ['pqr', 23.2], ['adsf', 232.12]]`

interactive way:

```
user_input = input("enter a literal python list/dict/whatever")
```

As opposed to `eval`, `ast.literal_eval` is limited but safe. It can only evaluate literal constructs, but nested lists & dicts are not a problem.

Comment: the **users** list I showed is just an example. my list contains a list of people with their names and age, just for example. @Jean-Francois

Comment: maybe OP needs example `users = ast.literal_eval(user_input)` and `print(users[0][0]) # 'abc'`. Or maybe OP needs even `user_input = input()` :)

Comment: @MoidShaikh that should work too, as long as there are no references to already existing variables in your script (in which case you would need `eval` but it's better to avoid it).

Answer (score 0):

also i found this

```
var = [[input(), float(input())] for _ in range(int(input()))]
```

very helpful